# Router Config IP Rejected

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, wifi-configuration

I'm currently using a D-Link DIR-601 router, and up until now, I have had very few problems with it. I've connected to the router control panel before using the IP 192.168.0.1. However, sometimes I would first have to restart my router for it to let me connect. After some research, I determined that it was a IP clash between my router and my modem, so I changed my router's IP to 192.168.0.4, which seemed to fix the problem. However, a couple months later, I tried connecting to 192.168.0.4, but my connection keeps getting rejected. In Opera, I get this error message:
"Opera's connection attempt to 192.168.0.4 was rejected. The website may be down, or your network may not be properly configured."
In IE, I just get a "This page can’t be displayed" error. I'd really appreciate any assistance.

Comment: What model is your modem? Is it also a router?

Comment: I'm not sure what my modem is. I am using a router that runs into a data outlet for my university.

Comment: What the router's WAN IP? Is it a private IP or a public one?

Answer (score 1):

I've dealt with a similar issue just yesterday and I think I know what is going on here...

It sounds like a mixture of a routing conflict between WAN and LAN along with security policies being applied.

If you have 192.168.0.1 as your modem and 192.168.0.4 on your router, you are effectively telling your router that the 192.168.0.0/24 network exists on both WAN and LAN... If on top of this, your router has a security policy that tells it to block access to the GUI on the WAN IP range, it will then block you from connecting.

I highly recommend you change your modem to 192.168.1.1 and set your router's WAN port to 192.168.1.2, then you can continue to use 192.168.0.0/24 on your LAN.

Alternatively, do it the other way round and set your LAN's ip range to something different, but you will need to change settings on anything statically assigned.

As for why you connected before, it is possible that the firewall policy to block accessing the GUI is hard coded to the WAN ip range, but, this only applies when the interface is up... try unplugging the modem and then seeing if you can connect... I can't guarantee this will work, but it may.

Hope this helps and also makes sense.

Comment: After rebooting the router a couple more times, it finally let me into the control panel. I was able to change the IP of the router to 192.168.1.2. I then became unable to connect to the internet for some time. However, after coming back from classes, it had somehow fixed itself and allowed me onto the internet with the router IP of 192.168.1.2. Unfortunately, after prolonged use of the router (6+ hours?), I get locked out of the control panel again and have to reboot repeatedly to get back in. So the problem has been downgraded to an annoyance, but any suggestions would still be appreciated.

Comment: I am guessing after changing the router's IP, you didn't change the ip on your computers... Make sure they have a new DHCP lease with the gateway of 192.168.2.1 and an ip of 192.168.2.x - if you were able to get on at all, I guess you do have that... As for loosing control over the router, I think you need a new one - it just sounds bad/bugged now...

Comment: I would never use a 192.168.0.x,  192.168.1.x,  192.168.168.x for a router, those subnets are too common and the default in many devices. I would recommend setting the router to something like 192.168.47.1, 192.168.183.1, or just about anything else, it just reduces potential issues.

Answer (score 0):

For your problem getting locked out, it sounds like a firmware issue. Here is the link to the page to download firmware. Only thing you need to go find out on your router, is which hardware revision it is, which should should be located on the bottom of it, or where ever it has model number.

Once you download the most up to date firmware, its a matter of going to your routers control panel, find the area to upload the firmware, usually its in the administration area. Then update the firmware.

[D-Link DIR-601 Firmware](http://support.dlink.com/ProductInfo.aspx?m=DIR-601)